# Async Task Stops Working, works when debugging with break points - Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-camera

My Async task is doing heavy image processing, a single Async task works successfully but if i try to execute multiple Async tasks i.e. before the first one is completed it stops working...
Though it works perfectly when i debug and insert have break points to check the problem.

I only need to have break point onActivityResult

```
    private class ProcessVideoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    int goodPointsLocal;
    int badPointsLocal;
    String videoFileLocal;
    ArrayList<Integer> xposLocal;
    ArrayList<Integer> yposLocal;
    ArrayList<String> markerSelectedLocal;
    int windowXxLocal;
    int windowYyLocal;

    public ProcessVideoTask(int _goodPoints, int _badPoints,
            String _videoFile, ArrayList<Integer> _xpos,
            ArrayList<Integer> _ypos, ArrayList<String> _markerSelected,
            int _windowXx, int _windowYy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        goodPointsLocal = _goodPoints;
        badPointsLocal = _badPoints;
        videoFileLocal = _videoFile;
        xposLocal = _xpos;
        yposLocal = _ypos;
        markerSelectedLocal = _markerSelected;
        windowXxLocal = _windowXx;
        windowYyLocal = _windowYy;

    }

    // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
        notGotoBack = false;
        String path = videoFileLocal;
        ProcessVDOToImages(path);
        try {//get frames from video and edit individually (heavy processing)
            PutMarkersOnImages(xposLocal, yposLocal, markerSelectedLocal,
                    Constants.RT_EVALUATE_TRAINING, windowXxLocal,
                    windowYyLocal);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        mFilePathMarkers = ProcessImagestoVdo();//append audio to frames (heavy)
        SetAudioWithMarkerVDO(mFilePathMarkers, videoFileLocal);

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        File savePathWMarker = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/HumanFocus/MarkerFrame/");

        File savePathWOMarker = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/HumanFocus/WithoutMarkerFrame/");

        if (savePathWMarker.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = savePathWMarker.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                new File(savePathWMarker, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }

        if (savePathWOMarker.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = savePathWOMarker.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                new File(savePathWOMarker, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }
        // change this if no Marker Video
        File src = new File("");
        File dst = new File("");
        if (mFilePathMarkers != null) {
            src = new File(mFilePathMarkers);
        }
        if (videoFileLocal != null) {
            dst = new File(videoFileLocal);
        }
        try {
            copyFile(src, dst);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int maxNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mCreateTraining.getAttachedFiles().size(); i++) {

            String fileName = mCreateTraining.getAttachedFiles().get(i)
                    .getDisplayName().substring(0, 2);

            if (isNumeric(fileName)) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(fileName) > maxNumber)
                    maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(fileName);
            }
        }

        mCreateTraining.attachFile(saveVideo(videoFileLocal,
                Constants.RT_CREATE_TRAINING, goodPointsLocal,
                badPointsLocal, maxNumber, videoFileLocal));
        updateReportItemsList();
        Toast.makeText(CreateTrainingActivity.this,
                "Video Processing is Successfully Completed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        notGotoBack = true;
    }
}
```

To avoid over-processing i try to run it serially rather then parallel, to do it manually i made this timer.

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (processList.size() > 0) {
                if (processList.get(0).getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {

                    processList.remove(0);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (processList.size() > 0) {
                        processList.get(0).execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```

And on activity result from the camera, Async task is created and inserted in the processList (ArrayList of AsyncTask)

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECORD_VIDEO_ACTIVITY) {
        if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateTrainingActivity.this,
                    "Video is Processing.. Please Wait ...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            goodPoints = data.getExtras().getInt("goodPoints", 0);
            badPoints = data.getExtras().getInt("badPoints", 0);
            videoFile = data.getExtras().getString("data");
            Xpos = data.getIntegerArrayListExtra("Xpos");
            Ypos = data.getIntegerArrayListExtra("Ypos");
            MarkerSelected = data.getStringArrayListExtra("MarkerSelected");

            windowXx = data.getExtras().getInt("windowXx");
            windowYy = data.getExtras().getInt("windowYy");

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////// Put tasks into queue

            ProcessVideoTask mTask = new ProcessVideoTask(goodPoints,
                    badPoints, videoFile, Xpos, Ypos, MarkerSelected,
                    windowXx, windowYy);

            processList.add(mTask);

            if (processList.size() == 1) {
                processList.get(0).execute();
            }

        }
```

This is my logcat

```
09-17 10:09:23.108: E/sizeee addxxxxxxxxxx(21007): 96
09-17 10:09:23.148: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 144.206MB for 11059216-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.218: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 151.585MB for 7738604-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.248: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1794
09-17 10:09:23.248: E/sizeee addxxxxxxxxxx(21007): 99
09-17 10:09:23.278: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 144.206MB for 11059216-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.368: E/sizeee addxxxxxxxxxx(21007): 102
09-17 10:09:23.418: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 144.206MB for 11059216-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.478: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 151.585MB for 7738604-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.508: E/sizeee addxxxxxxxxxx(21007): 105
09-17 10:09:23.538: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 144.206MB for 11059216-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.608: E/sizeee addxxxxxxxxxx(21007): 108
09-17 10:09:23.668: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 144.206MB for 11059216-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.728: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 151.585MB for 7738604-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.758: E/sizeee addxxxxxxxxxx(21007): 111
09-17 10:09:23.788: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 144.207MB for 11059216-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.838: E/sizeee addxxxxxxxxxx(21007): 114
09-17 10:09:23.868: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 151.586MB for 11059216-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:23.908: I/dalvikvm-heap(21007): Grow heap (frag case) to 158.966MB for 7738604-byte allocation
09-17 10:09:25.478: D/MediaRecorder(21007): Current Package Name: uk.org.humanfocus.hfi
09-17 10:09:25.488: I/Choreographer(21007): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 10:09:25.488: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1791
09-17 10:09:26.498: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1790
09-17 10:09:27.508: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1789
09-17 10:09:28.508: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1788
09-17 10:09:29.508: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1787
09-17 10:09:30.508: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1786
09-17 10:09:30.678: I/user interaction(21007): called
09-17 10:09:30.678: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1799
09-17 10:09:31.698: I/millisUntilFinished:(21007): 1798
09-17 10:09:31.698: I/On Pause :(21007): called
09-17 10:09:32.318: I/Choreographer(21007): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Use Listeners to know the execution status of the Async task check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534418/how-to-make-asynctask-modular-in-android/23534743#23534743

Comment: am sorry but this log doesnt speak about any crash, can you take new logact dump with crash log and put it here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case you should use Android Service or Intent Service.
Link:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

You shouldn't use Async for long heavy operations.
In my case I used Intent Service with new Runnables in it and it worked.
If you have more questions, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your logcat, the final line is interesting:

```
09-17 10:09:32.318: I/Choreographer(21007): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The importance of this is suggested to me by the fact that it works during debugging - when breakpoints give it plenty of time to catch up!

As a general rule, @dadecki is probably right: for this much processing on android you should probably use a background service. However, if you don't wish to pursue that path, it would seem seem sensible to ask the question: why is the app doing too much work on the main thread. A couple of suggestions:

- Move as much as you can out of `onPostExecute` and into `doInBackground` - there sweems to be a lot of code there!
- Look at what else the app is doing in the main thread at the same time: are there other things in your code that should really be in async tasks (or a service).

Once you've dealt with this issue, you will be in a much better place to determine what is still goin wrong (if anything).

Answer (score 1):

For your case, it is recommended to use use [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). Because at a time you can have limited number of AsynTask. Please [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117183/why-use-asynctaskloader-with-loadermanager-instead-of-simple-handler#answer-13117632) In debugging it may be working fine, because at break point, system gets a time to finish the pending AsyncTask & that's why maximum pool size will never reach in debugging.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Increase Thread sleep time and see now it is 1 sec make it to 5 sec or 10 sec..

```
 try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```